# cruise control .net : xcopy not working for copying files to remote server

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, xcopy

I am trying to copy a folder to a remote machine using xcopy. This command is executed via cruise control task. I can run `xcopy source destOnRemoteMachine` successfully if i am running it from command prompt. But if i am executing it from cruise control .net, it is always complaining about "Invalid drive specification" error.

I tried :

```
> <exec
> executable="c:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe">
>                 <baseDirectory>$(BASE)\Project</baseDirectory>
>                 <buildArgs>.\*.* RemoteMachine\Project /Y</buildArgs>
>                 <buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>
>                 <successExitCodes>-1,0,1</successExitCodes>
>               </exec>
```

and :

```
<exec executable="c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe">
        <baseDirectory>$(BASE)\Project</baseDirectory>
        <buildArgs>/C xcopy $(BASE)\Project\*.* RemoteMachine /y</buildArgs>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>30</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        <successExitCodes>-1,0,1</successExitCodes>
      </exec>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your answer. Putting xcopy in batch was also not helpful, the problem was something else. here is problem:

It was problem with the account on which Cruise Control .net service was running. It was running as local service. Thus was not able to see the network path. I changed CCNet Service to run on a domain account which have permission to read/ write on remote machine. This solved my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file using `xcopy source destOnRemoteMachine` command and execute that bat file using `<exec>` command in cruise control .net

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running CC as a user account, after having used `NET USE` to persistently map a drive letter to a network share on another domain. Although it worked in a desktop session, CC could still not get to the share as part of the build. Executing `NET USE` as part of the build (without a drive mapping) allowed the copy to succeed.

```
<exec program="net" verbose="true">
  <arg value="use" />
  <arg value="\\server\share" />
  <arg value="password" />
  <arg value="/user:domain\username" />
</exec>
```